# NodeJS cucumber get overal statistic in AfterAll hook

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

Help please to find a solution how to get overall statistic of tests of status of execution.
Tried to find in debug any place where this status or overall statistic may present.
For example for scenario I can get it via `scenario.result.status`. And for feature can not find. And for all suite execution also.